# silent vs. silent! - What is the difference?

Tags: vimscript

This might be a silly question, or someone may say it lacks research, but I really cannot understand what does the exclamation mark after `silent` mean.

For example, in the following function that removes extra characters such as `^M`:

```
function! RemoveExtraCharacters()
  let l:initialCol = getcurpos()[2]
  let l:line = getline('.')[0:initialCol-1]

  let l:numRemoved = len(l:line) - len(substitute(l:line, '[^[:print:]\t]', '', 'g'))

  let l:save = winsaveview()
  keeppatterns silent! %s/[^[:print:]\t]//g
  call winrestview(l:save)

  if l:numRemoved != 0
    call cursor(line('.'), (l:initialCol-l:numRemoved))
  endif
endfun
autocmd! BufWritePre * call RemoveExtraCharacters()
```

> You can either use `:silent` or `:silent!` as a prefix to any command or you can add the `e` option to the substitute, which is often easier.
>
> ```
> :%s/x/y/ge
> :silent! %s/x/y/g
> :silent %s/x/y/g
> ```
>
> - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1043613

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's explained in `:help :silent`

```
                        *:sil* *:silent* *:silent!*
:sil[ent][!] {command}  Execute {command} silently.  Normal messages will not
            be given or added to the message history.
            When [!] is added, error messages will also be
            skipped, and commands and mappings will not be aborted
            when an error is detected.  |v:errmsg| is still set.
            When [!] is not used, an error message will cause
            further messages to be displayed normally.
```

This is one of those examples where punctuation in the argument to `:help` makes a difference.

- `:help silent` takes you to the `-silent` help topic
- `:help :silent` takes you to the `:silent` command

Comment: Yes, I erroneously tried `help silent` without the colon, thanks. So it seems `:%s/x/y/ge` works the same as `:silent! %s/x/y/g`, but not the same as `:silent %s/x/y/g` (which is the "weaker" option), right?

Comment: Might want to mention `:h help-summary` which explains the help topic syntax (`:foo`, `-foo`, `'foo'`, `i_foo`, etc.)

Comment: `silent colo mightnotexist` will error if there is no colorscheme, `silent! colo mightnotexist` will not.